# Creating a Win32 Application in Qt Creator

Tags: qt, winapi, compatibility, qt-creator

I'm looking to create a win32 application in Qt Creator - is this possible? If so, how would I go about doing it? My preference would definitely be to use native C code (and the native API) if possible.

Comment: It has absolutely no sense to use cross-platform IDE for native, win-only development. Why don't you use Express version of MS Visual Studio instead? It is also free. This would be much more comfortable and productive way in your case...

Comment: Trust me, I was going to go that route. Until I found out that their C compiler (from my experience) wasn't very good...I spent hours trying to figure out how to tweak it to what I was looking for and it still wouldn't build my code! Qt Creator builds it fine, however. Now, I need to just figure out how to link win32 apps and use their WinMain function as my entry point.

Comment: @vitakot: Well, I am doing Windows only development using Microsoft's compilers and Qt Creator as an IDE. I find that writing code is much more pleasant using Qt Creator.

Comment: Agreed. For one, you're able to actually choose what compiler to use...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use Qt Creator just as an IDE. It doesn't force you to use Qt or C++ only.

1. Create project for Qt Console Application
2. From .pro file remove "QT += core"
3. From main.cpp remove all Qt stuff
4. Include required WinAPI headers
5. Write C-code only
6. ...
7. Profit

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to be tied to Qt at all, Qt Creator supports CMake. Create your CMakeLists.txt then open the file as a project in Qt Creator.