# Can I use Qt Creator for non-gui programming on C?

Tags: linux, qt, qt-creator

Can I use the Qt Creator IDE for non-GUI programming? Now, compiling "Hello world" like plain C project:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I get an error

> :-1: error: Circular all <- project dependency dropped.

What did I do wrong?

I found the solution. In Tools - Options - Environment in Terminal a wrote **xterm -e** and it worked :) Thanks for all.

Comment: What happens if you add the required `#include <stdio.h>` to the top?

Comment: It was added. I didn't print it in my code block, sorry.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386426/creating-a-win32-application-in-qt-creator

Comment: In my .pro file  doesn't QT += core. I added in the .pro QT -= core, but I get error again.

Comment: Yes, I have a friend who swears by it for his professional projects.

Comment: I just ran your program under Qt Creator 2.4.1 under Windows 7, and I didn't have any problem. Changing a terminal setting might affect how the program's output is displayed, but it shouldn't have anything to do with the ":-1: error: Circular all <- project dependency dropped." message you reported.

Comment: You need at at least QT -= gui and CONFIG += console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using QtCreator for writing a console app in C. I just have the following at the top of the project file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= qt
```

And then the usual stuff to include sources (eg, SOURCES += main.c). Seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Theorically you can do this. All C programs are supposed to compile in C++.

Comment: Well... For example, the function declaration `void f()` means different things in C and C++, so the call `f(0)`, while valid in C, won't compile in C++.

Comment: No, not *all* C programs are valid C++ programs. For example, `int class;` is a legal C declaration, but a syntax error in C++.

Comment: @myrkos: Correct -- but it's close, and apart from the missing `#include <stdio.h>` the OP's C program is valid C++.

Answer (score 0):

QT has special class for non-gui apps, it's called QCoreApplication.